# How to wait until a file finishes writing before using it?

Tags: node.js, discord.js, fs

I have a png file being created but when i'm trying to use it it tries to do so before it finishes writing it

how would I make it wait until the file is done writing before using it?

```
                PImage.encodePNGToStream(img, fs.createWriteStream('template.out.png'));

            channel.send("Drawn By: "+req.body["Drawer"], { files: ["./template.out.png"] });
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [PImage-docs](https://github.com/joshmarinacci/node-pureimage) `encodePNGToStream` is asynchronous and returns a promise. So you have to `await` or use `then(...)`.

E.g

```js
await PImage.encodePNGToStream(img, fs.createWriteStream('template.out.png'));
channel.send("Drawn By: "+req.body["Drawer"], { files: ["./template.out.png"] });
```

or

```js
PImage.encodePNGToStream(img, fs.createWriteStream('template.out.png')).then(_ => channel.send("Drawn By: "+req.body["Drawer"], { files: ["./template.out.png"] }));
```